# Why is my program not displaying the username?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am a beginner at PHP and I don't understanding why the code below isn't displaying the user name, as there are no error messages. I have double checked my work and I still can't find an error.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = query($sql);

confirm($result);

$row = fetch_array($result);

echo $row['username'];

?>
```

This is the `db.php` file I have created:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','login_db');

function escape($string) {
    global $con; 

    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string);
}


function query($query) {

    global $con;

    return mysqli_query($con,$query);
}


function fetch_array($result){
    global $con;   

    mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

function confirm($result) {
    global $con;

    if(!$result) {

        die("Query Failed" . mysqli_error($con)); 
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Add `return` in front of `mysqli_fetch_array` in you db file.

Comment: Also if you're new to PHP consider using object-oriented PHP and avoid global variables.

Comment: Suggestion: Transform your db.php file into a class. Avoid the use of global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created the function `fetch_array` in your `db.php` file, but don't have a return statement, so it doesn't actually return the array.

Change it to this, to include the `return` statement.

```
function fetch_array($result){
    global $con;   

    return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Comment: forgot return statement